# PHP~ Convert String to an Array

Tags: php, regex

I have this string:

```
array('type' => 'button', 'value' => 35);
```

Simple question: How can I convert this string into an array?

The problem is, `eval` sucks and `explode(",",$string)` catches the wrong commas sometimes:

```
array('t,y,p,e' => 'bu,t,t,o,n', 'va,,,l,,ue' => '3,,,,,5');
```

Comment: what's the source of the string?

Comment: array('type' => 'button', 'value' => 35) isn't a string, it's an array. Do you mean the string inside the array?

Comment: @EduardoMoratto I think he means that is the value of the string.

Comment: @eduardo - the string contains the syntax for an array, but is not itself an array

Comment: You mean something like [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php#77958)?

Comment: Look into https://gist.github.com/hakre/1102761, by Stack Overflow member hakre.

Comment: why would you even have that as a string?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: My thoughts exactly. =)

Comment: What's wrong with `eval` when using it for the only excusable reason possible - parsing PHP code that is dynamically supplied to you by a third party... it's like webdesigners refusing to use tables for tabular data because 'tables are evil'. The feature is still there, use it for the things it *should* do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt you'll find a function to read a string as code outside of eval. So assuming you always have the same rigid structure, you could do something like this -

```
$str = "array('type' => 'button', 'value' => 35)";
preg_match_all('/\(.*?\)/', $str, $arr);

if(isset($arr[0]))
{
  $array = array();
  $items = explode(",", substr($arr[0][0], 1, -1));
  foreach($items AS $i)
  {
    $kv = explode(" => ", $i);
    $array[str_replace("'", "", trim($kv[0]))] = str_replace("'", "", trim($kv[1]));
  }

  print_r($array);
}
```

Which is pretty hideous, but is a quick hack to extract the array from the string. I'm not saying this is a "good" solution to your problem, but it is a quick fix and would work for what you provided as an example.

Feel free to ask questions or by all means suggest a better solution.